# multiple dynamic payments using paypal

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

am going to develop a website in php where user can place their items for selling and other user can buy these items and we as the site owner will be deducting some amount for giving services.
i'v steadied paypal but paypal don't allow the multiple dynamic payments.it allows multiple fixed payments.
i want to allow dynamic payments so that if a user post an item for selling and other user buy it,the buying amount would be shifted to my account and after service charge deduction i would be able to transfer payment to seller. 
can anybody tell me that whether paypal allow this or is there any other payment gateway which  would allow this.
any help would be much appreciated.
thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [Adaptive Payments platform](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/).  I would recommend looking into [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) specifically.